Spring Integration - Support for SMPP
Does Spring Integration support SMPP (Short Message Peer-to-Peer) protocol? Have checked the documentation, couldn't find one for SMPP in particular.

There is some extension module: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/tree/main/spring-integration-smpp.
But it would need more love to be realigned with modern software.

Thanks Artem, any plans for the realignment? SMS is still a popular medium of notification along with EMAIL. Kindly consider.

That repository is fully in hands of community. Feel free to contribute whatever you'd like!
